# When is one heuristic better than another?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I answered a question in which two heuristics were given for which A* was to be conducted to find a path from a start state to a goal state.

One of the heuristics found a path by expanding one node less - now for this reason, would we say this heuristic is better than the other?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that the same heuristic won't expand 15 more nodes in another graph?

Comment: @beaker I don't? But... im guessing the heuristics are specific for just this problem- not for another!

Comment: If your program finds the shortest route between two cities, given the highways that connect them, you would expect the same heuristic to work in Canada or Czech Republic, right? The heuristic should solve the **problem** (shortest route), not the **instance** of the problem (route between Montreal and Vancouver).

Comment: you're right. hmm so how would i go about determining which of the heuristics is best? its only worth 2 marks though, so im guessing it is specific to this exact instance of the problem (start node A to goal state H)?

Comment: What is the definition of an admissible heuristic?

Comment: An admissible heuristic is one where the distances are never overestimated

Comment: Do we look at the distances and check if any are overestimates? Then they cannot be admissible and therefore not a good alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot say that one heuristic is "better" than another simply because it expands fewer nodes on one example of a problem. On the next example, the "better" heuristic might expand many more nodes than the other.

We know that a heuristic estimate can't go over the actual distance if it is to be admissible. In other words, the heuristic function must be constructed in such a way that it will never overestimate the distance to the goal under any circumstances.

It make sense, then, that if one heuristic gets *closer* to the actual distance without going over, it can be considered "better". If you used a heuristic that said that the distance between any two nodes was `1` (or any value less than the shortest edge length) you would end up expanding a lot of nodes. As the estimate gets closer to the actual distance you make it more likely that you can eliminate paths earlier.

There are, of course, other ways of defining "better", such as being easier to calculate.

Comment: Thanks mate, understood it. Turns out one of the entries in the heuristic table was indeed an overestimate.